# Code is executing both if and else when if is true

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

This code is executing both if and else, any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
  foreach($each_item as $key => $product)
  {
    foreach($new_item as $key2 => $newproduct)
    {
      if (in_array($product['product_id'], $newproduct)) {
        $this->update_order_items($order_id, $product['product_id'], array(
            "quantity" => $newproduct['quantity'], 
            "price" => $newproduct['price']       
            ));
      }
      else
      {
        $this->delete_order_items($order_id, $product['product_id']);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: yes. both may be executed. what is the problem?

Comment: When the if statement is true, it still executes the else

Comment: both executed for the same item of the loop?

Comment: No I'm testing with two items, with one item its working, just realized that

Comment: Hi, thank you first of all. I'm trying it out now but I had fixed if by adding true in the if statement then I added an elseif with false and doing nothing in the else

Comment: @dhruvJadia hi, I just realized that you code will not work because the second parameter of in_array requires an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please let us know result of above code?

```
foreach($each_item as $key => $product)
  {
    foreach($new_item as $key2 => $newproduct)
    {
      if (in_array($product['product_id'], $newproduct)) {
        echo '1';
      }
      else
      {
       echo '2'; 
      }
      exit;
    }
  }
```